# Build a WCF with generic type

Tags: c#, wcf, generics

I want to build a service that will pass the data read from the database to the client in JSON format. I don't know the schema table and the types.

I thought about implementing the WCF over Dictionary but the JSON is very complicated and contains objects like "key = ...; value = ..." and i want just "key=value" and i need to return list of Dictionary objects. Sometimes from database i will receive a comma separated array, so i will insert in my Dictionary a key with a new Dictionary as value.

In PHP my boss said that it can be done through associative arrays. Please help me with some ideas or link because i don't know where to start to look.

If there is something that you didn't understood please comment and i will try another explanation.

Edits:

1. I need it to be a rest service, so JSON is mandatory.
2. How can i load data from the table ? What type can i use ?

Edit #2 : This is what i want to get : [CorectJSON](http://pastebin.com/YbF8k45V)

Edit #3 : This is my current json :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [areaGetStreetTypesResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [responseMessage] => [{"name":"IMPASSE","street_type":"IMP"}{"name":"LOTISSEMENT","street_type":"LOT"}{"name":"ROUTE","street_type":"RTE"}{"name":"RUE","street_type":"RUE"}]
            [response_status] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [message] => Success : JSON created into the responseMessage variable !
                    [status] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

Is not containing some commas between so it cannot be decoded by php. What should i do ?

This is my method [Code](http://pastebin.com/bky752X8)

Comment: If you need it to be a REST service: I've posted a link on how to generate a REST service that returns JSON without you doing anything special! Read the links in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the reason why you need to pass JSON? If you want to create a WCF REST service, it is sufficient to tell WCF to create JSON messages as described here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/327420/WCF-REST-Service-with-JSON

If you access the service from a C# application, you don't need to care about how data is passed back and forth. Just take "normal" method parameters and use return values like you'd do locally and you're set.

Example:

```
string[] GetResultStrings(List<Rectangle> sourceRectangles);
```

If you really need to pass JSON strings, just pass strings and use the JSON serializer and deserializer to encode the reply and decode the parameters.

For example:

```
string GetJSONString(string jsonRequest);
```

The following information may help on using the JSON serializer and deserializer: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/272335/JSON-Serialization-and-Deserialization-in-ASP-NET

**EDIT**
I'm using the following method to serialize serializable objects to JSON:

```
public static string SerializeJSON(this object obj)
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        serializer.WriteObject(ms, obj);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
    }
}
```

This works just fine for any `DataContract` class like:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyJSONReturnableClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ThisBecomesANamedString;

    [DataMember]
    public MyJSONReturnableClass[] AndWorksAlsoForNestedArrays;
}
```

Comment: my client is a php application. how can i load my data into the returned string ? i tryied writing directly the json string but it returnes a lot of "\"" because i need " in json string and i need to escape it, si it's not a clean json.

Comment: On the PHP side, use the `json_decode` function (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), to return JSON from the service, you'd serialize the C# object using the `JSONSerializer` as described in the link I provided. Only thing: The object must be serializable!

Comment: "my client is a php application." - That info should be in the original question.

Comment: Please see my edit on how I serialize C# objects to JSON in one of my applications where I pass and receive JSON from C# to/from a PHP REST service.

Comment: my problem is that i cannot have a fixed class. sometimes i get from database only string columns, but sometimes i get int too or arrays too. maybe if i will use something like List<Dictionary<Object, Object>> i will be able to load all my returned rows.  can my DataContrat not be present ?

Comment: Please read the first link I've provided on how to create a WCF REST service that returns JSON - you don't need to do anything, WCF can do it for you!

Comment: i know that wcf take cares of my json serialization but the object that arrives at client is not good, and i have to make a custom serialization or something.

Comment: Could you edit your question to provide that information and a sample of the "bad JSON" you're getting in PHP?

Answer (score 2):

I think that doing everything as a dictionary in webservice API is bad practice and I hate when I need to work with API's like this. If it is a WCF, it produces WSDL and WDSL describes the data is going in and out, so if everything is dictionary, WSDL can not provide anything meaningfull, so your datacontracts tell you nothing about the data.
If you need simply forward database data through webservice, WCF has DataServices http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106 although I think you should create API that fits your business needs and is not simple proxy between database and your client.

Answer (score 1):

Populate your dictionary, then serialize it using JSon.
Pass it to your client using WCF or RabbitMq...

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourDict);
```

Download the NewtonSoft.dll

Put using:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Comment: I've posted a link in my answer on how to create a REST service that returns JSON without you having to touch JSON at all. Please read the links.